# Помогите пытаюсь узнать что скопировано и записать в файл почему не получается?

Tags: python

```
import pyperclip


old = ' '
while True:
   s = pyperclip.paste()
   if(s != old):
       old = s
       print(old)
       break
   f =  open('Копия.txt', 'r+')
   f.write(old)
   f.close()
```

Comment: У Вас запись в файл происходит в цикле `while`. Если скопированная строка не будет равна `old`, то до записи в файл дело никогда не дойдет. Вынесите её за пределы цикла.

Comment: Jazzis, Спасибо!